# Feature-testing a REST API with unittest in Django

Tags: python, django, mocking, django-unittest

In our Django project, we have some API views that are defined in `urls.py` like this:

```
path('api/calendar/calendar_data', calendar_api.serve_data),
```

and our `calendar_api` is an instance of `CalendarAPI`, which is instantiated above:

```
from main.calendar_api import CalendarAPI
from caldav import DAVClient
...
calendar_api = CalendarAPI(client=DAVClient(...))
```

In the CalendarAPI class we have a method that fetches data from a remote CalDAV calendar using the caldav library like so:

```
class CalendarAPI(ApiEndpoint):
...
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.caldav_client = client

  def _get_event_list(self):
    return self.caldav_client.principal().calendars()[0].events()
```

We wish to mock this method in a way such that _get_event_list returns a predefined array.

Our test case looks like this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from django.test import SimpleTestCase

class TestCalendar(SimpleTestCase):
  @patch('main.urls.CalendarAPI')
  def test_response_format(self, calendarapi_mock):
    calendarapi_mock._get_event_list.return_value = mocked_calendar_events
    response = self.client.get('/api/calendar/calendar_data', format='json')
    # fails test if response does not match mocked_calendar_events
    self._compareResponse(response, mocked_calendar_events)
```

No matter what we try, we can't get mocking to work. If anyone knows of a better way to instantiate classes in `urls.py` in light of mocking, please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

This always gets me as well. To mock a method on an **instance** of `CalendarAPI`, you need to mock the method on the [`return_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) of the mock (`calendarapi_mock.return_value`).

With `calendarapi_mock._get_event_list.return_value`, you're mocking the method on the `CalendarAPI` **class** instead, i.e. `CalendarAPI._get_event_list()`.

So instead of

```
calendarapi_mock._get_event_list.return_value = mocked_calendar_events
```

use:

```
calendarapi_mock.return_value._get_event_list.return_value = mocked_calendar_events
```